# Regex issue in number of occurrences

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement validate parameters. My parameters can take any characters with spaces and other symbols, but the number of substrings should be limited, like `{1,128}`

My regex pattern is:

```
^*[a-zA-Z0-9~@#$^*%()_+=\{}\[\]|\\,.?: -]*${1,5}
```

Test input is 'My name is Rani and Age 58'

Though I need to use maximum five words I can put any number of words without errors.

Comment: You need to define what is "word delimiter" and what constitute a "word", then you can write the regex by using the form: `^(<Word>+<Word_delim>+){0,<n-1>}<Word>+$`

Comment: @user2622132 This seems to be one of those `not-so-well-defined-problems`. As asked in previous comment you really need to define what you consider a `"word"` here and provide some sample input/output values.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
String str = "My name is Rani and Age 58";
if(str.split("\\s").length>0 && str.split("\\s").length<129)
    System.out.println("Accepted");
else
    System.out.println("Rejected");
```